# How to customise or style the auth UX in dotnet core 3

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-3.0

The Core3/react template with authentication sets up identity and all the UX required to manage it.

What I can't figure out is how to customise or at least style this.

In Core2 I would have had to create all of this myself, so it would be merely a matter of importing another stylesheet. But with all the UI canned, there's no obvious mechanism to add styling. It uses bootstrap referenced out of its npm_modules, and I suppose I could hack that to add styles but it's ugly and vulnerable to updates.

What's the preferred approach?

In particular I'd like to add `margin-bottom: 0.5em` to the buttons on the login page because when a lot of OAuth providers are registered and the buttons wrap to another line there's no margin between them and it looks terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When people want to use React with dotnet core3 they don't get there by wading through thousands of pages of mostly irrelevant documentation. Life's too short.

Instead they bash out a query like `dotnet core3 react authentication oauth` 
 and start their journey by skimming [Introduction to authentication for Single Page Apps on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for the bits on React.

Without getting into a rant about how much prior knowledge is assumed for the section on deployment to Azure, down the bottom there's a link [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Those of us habitually using VS Code will ignore this because Scaffolding is a Visual Studio thing. This is a mistake. Take the blue pill and go down the rabbit hole of scaffolding, because now it's a CLI thing too, and this is how you deal with the problem I describe in the question, of how to customise code you don't have.

You scaffold it, and then you do have the code.